# Run automatically schedule in xampp with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler

I have defined a command and make it can run every minutes in Kernel with schedule. But when i use artisan command to run, it only run once time.So, i want to make it run auto every minutes in Xampp in window 10. But how can i add :
 `* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to my server
Can i have run scheduler automatic?
In :

```
public function handle()
{
        $banMember = MemberAccount::where('isBan',1)->get();
        foreach($banMember as $ban)
        {
            $ban->isBan = 0;
            $ban->save();
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some hints for you to do the task scheduling

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-with-windows
http://www.z-cron.com/

`* * * * *` means that it has to be running every minute.

Comment: thanks sir. But i have written schedule in kernel.php but this guide suggest example :  http://www.example.com/cron.php. Can i change cron.php = kernel.php ?

Comment: cronjob is used to run a command. it doesn't matter what command is that. curl / php or other system commands. for laravel you should do :

Comment: php -q /path/to/laravel/artisan schedule:run

Comment: It is laravel not Drupal!